# How to center the title of an AppBar with theme [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to `center` all the titles in my app with `theme`, theres a way to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

Centering App Bar using Theme

```
theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(centerTitle: true),),
```

Comment: or also one can use `copywith` too

Comment: The only properties i can modify in `AppBarTheme` are `this.brightness, this.color, this.elevation, this.iconTheme, this.actionsIconTheme, this.textTheme,`. There is not `this.centerTitle`

Comment: I didn't just send it. I tried on DartPad and its work.

Comment: I just saw in [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/df64d1b303c40dccd295105ef02c4fa7abd76464/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart) there is this.centerTitle.

Answer (score 1):

use `centerTitle: true`

```
appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Appbar Title"),
      ),
```

Comment: The question asks how to do with `theme`